# Is it theoretically possible to create a Higgs field disruptor?

Tags: experimental-physics

A device that can disrupt the concentration of Higgs boson in region and make objects lose mass. And if not why?

Comment: Because Higgs bosons require many billion \$ projects to produce and they decay in $10^{-24} s$... but maybe the manipulation of the *Higgs field* wouldn't be impossible (personal opinion).

Comment: Can u think of a few ways to make it possible.

Comment: The Higgs field is a 4-component scalar field. 3 of its components couple to the weak field, which are vector fields, whose bosons ($W^+, W^-$ and $Z^\circ$) decay nearly so fast as the Higgs. But, there are many stable particles capable to interact with these field through different quantum numbers (electric charge, isospin and hypercharge) and these particles could be maybe manipulated by electromagnetic ways. Anyways, the 4 components of the Higgs field have a mexican hat potential (google for that), which results that zeroing the Higgs field is probably unreachable, but

Comment: rotating its components may be not. It would result that the rest mass of every elemental particle will change (grow or shrink). It would be enough to produce a wide range of interesting effects, for example the change of the electron rest mass would cause surely a wide range of chemical effects. But it is my personal naive opinion :-), and I am only an enthusiast.

Comment: I need to remove your last sentence because it makes your question incomprehensible.

Comment: I am sorry, but your second try was again only adding an incomprehensible sentence to your question. There is a complex review mechanism there, and if the other reviewers find your question incomprehensible, they will close and later delete it.

Comment: I am working on your question to save it, *you* commit every possible to make it VLQ (very low quality). Why the hell you can't formulate in clear sentences?